# Python: How do I RUN websocket once

Tags: python, sockets, web

There is the <ws_.run_forever()> function when calling on a websocket: is there a way to calling it once and/or get its first (and 1 and only) response and then terminate it?
This is the socket:

```
ws_ticks = websocket.WebSocketApp(apiUrl, on_message=on_messageTicks, on_open=on_openTicks)
```